# how to delete dynamic textbox created in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, dynamic, textbox

```
TextBox[] txt = new TextBox[4];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    txt[i] = new TextBox();
    txt[i].Text = "button" + i;
}
```

these are the codes to create dynamic textbox. i don't know how to delete these button. later i found  how to this textboxes this may help you in your project
this is the functin to delete the text box completly.

```
private void CleanForm(Control ctrl)
    {
        foreach (Control c in ctrl.Controls)
        {
            if (c is TextBox)
            {
                ((TextBox)c).Dispose();
                CleanForm(this);
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `CleanForm(this)` in the loop?  Also the garbage collector will eventually "delete" the textbox when you remove it from any container referencing it.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're keeping a reference to the textboxes when you're creating them `txt`, you could simply enumerate over that to remove.

```
foreach(TextBox t in txt){
    this.Controls.Remove(t);
    t.Dispose();
}

txt = new Textbox[] {}; // this removes all references to those textboxes. null would work too.
```

Answer (score 0):

Also it *seems* that the code is not complete, as much as it could be in one question, I would say, that:

`TextBox` control in order to be appeared on the `Form/Control` has to become a member for `Controls` collection of it. In other words, to "delete" (I suppose you're talking about remove from interface) you can do simply do something like this:

```
ctrl.Controls.Remove(textBoxControl);
textBoxControl.Dispose();
```

Hope this helps.